# How would a natural biological battery work?

Tags: biology, anatomy, biochemistry, electricity, bio-mechanics

Exactly what it says on the tin: what would be the structure and function of a naturally-evolved battery - i.e. a biological structure capable of storing electrical charge and powering an electrical circuit?

Please do not answer "a brain"; yes, I know it holds electricity, but those are electrical impulses that keep it functioning, rather than it being a storage organ in and of itself.

Comment: Are you sure you want this? Because chemical energy storage is much higher energy density than electrochemical storage. That's why we often use generators (and fuel cells for the really exotic applications) and not batteries. Are you sure you don't want something like a biological fuel cell instead?

Comment: Brains function on chemical signals not electric ones

Comment: @Rad140 No, brains are *regulated* by chemical signals. Neurons use electricity as their signal transmission method.

Comment: @DKNguyen I want something that can maintain a charge constantly, rather than something that produces it constantly.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE I hope you realize there is little distinction between the two. What's the difference between a pipe where water is flowing from it and a glass that is always full despite you drinking from it?

Comment: @DKNguyen A fuel cell might constantly be able to generate electrical charge, but I'm looking for something that's a storage medium, not a power source.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE You are going to have to define where the energy input is coming from then because as long as you don't, the fuel that a fuel cell runs on qualifies as a storage medium just like a battery or capacitor does (and a more biologically compatible one at that). Are you wanting this thing to be powered by lightning or static or something? Or a parasite that goes around searching for power lines? Even in that last case, siphoning electric power to crack water and store it as fuel is more biologically compatible than the battery or capacitor case.

Comment: @DKNguyen It's coming from a thermocouple. Still, I'd like to know how a biological battery could be made.

Comment: You'll need **electrocytes**.. https://www.google.com/search?q=electrocytes these are used by electric eels https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/article/151020-electric-eel-evolution-high-voltage-sensory-weapon-animals-science

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE: But the electrical activity of neurons isn't (generally) the same as electricity flowing in wires.  Instead, the neurons maintain a potential difference between inside and outside,  When a neuron fires an action potential, there's a wave of depolarization that propagates down the nerve fiber.  But the signal propagates at speeds around 100 m/sec, compared to the near light speed propagation of electric signals in for instance your computer's CPU.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nature has already been there, done that, got the T-shirt.

[Electric eels.](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-electric-eels-gene/) 500 volts and 1 amp.

> The electric eel generates large electric currents by way of a highly
> specialized nervous system that has the capacity to synchronize the
> activity of disc-shaped, electricity-producing cells packed into a
> specialized electric organ. The nervous system does this through a
> command nucleus that decides when the electric organ will fire. When
> the command is given, a complex array of nerves makes sure that the
> thousands of cells activate at once, no matter how far they are from
> the command nucleus.
>
> Each electrogenic cell carries a negative charge of a little less than
> 100 millivolts on its outside compared to its inside. When the command
> signal arrives, the nerve terminal releases a minute puff of
> acetylcholine, a neurotransmitter. This creates a transient path with
> low electrical resistance connecting the inside and the outside of one
> side of the cell. Thus, each cell behaves like a battery with the
> activated side carrying a negative charge and the opposite side a
> positive one.

As a point of clarification, batteries do NOT 'store electricity'. They store chemicals which, at the point of discharge, go through a chemical process which generates electricity. Capacitors store electricity. Rechargeable batteries use the applied electricity to reverse the chemical process, storing the energy in chemical form, for creating electricity later.

Comment: Upvoted.. same time, same idea (see comment)

Comment: Yeah, beat me to it, too :-)